# R: Using rvest package instead of XML package to get links from URL

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rvest

I use XML package to get the links from [this url](http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat).

```
# Parse HTML URL
v1WebParse <- htmlParse(v1URL)
# Read links and and get the quotes of the companies from the href
t1Links <- data.frame(xpathSApply(v1WebParse, '//a', xmlGetAttr, 'href'))
```

While this method is very efficient, I've used `rvest` and seems faster at parsing a web than `XML`. I tried `html_nodes` and `html_attrs` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `rvest` uses the `XML` package for the node extraction. It really shouldn't be any faster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Despite my comment, here's how you can do it with `rvest`. Note that we need to read in the page with `htmlParse` first since the site has the content-type set to `text/plain` for that file and that tosses `rvest` into a tizzy.

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)

pg <- htmlParse("http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat")
pg %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

##   [1] "/inf_corporativa71050_JAIME1CP1A.html" "/inf_corporativa10400_INTEGRC1.html"  
##   [3] "/inf_corporativa66100_ACESEGC1.html"   "/inf_corporativa71300_ADCOMEC1.html"  
## ...
## [273] "/inf_corporativa64801_VOLCAAC1.html"   "/inf_corporativa58501_YURABC11.html"  
## [275] "/inf_corporativa98959_ZNC.html"
```

That further illustrates `rvest`'s `XML` package underpinnings.

UPDATE

`rvest::read_html()` can handle this directly now:

```
pg <- read_html("http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat")
```

Comment: You are right, for the node extraction `rvest` uses `XML`. I'll discuss in the chat the difference in times for the sites on which I used the packages. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're looking for an `rvest` answer, but here's another way using the  `XML` package that might be more efficient than what you're doing.

Have you seen the `getLinks()` function in `example(htmlParse)`?  I use this modified version from the examples to get `href` links.  It's a handler function so we can collect the values as they are read, saving on memory and increasing efficiency.

```
links <- function(URL) 
{
    getLinks <- function() {
        links <- character()
        list(a = function(node, ...) {
                links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
                node
             },
             links = function() links)
        }
    h1 <- getLinks()
    htmlTreeParse(URL, handlers = h1)
    h1$links()
}

links("http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat")
#  [1] "/inf_corporativa71050_JAIME1CP1A.html"
#  [2] "/inf_corporativa10400_INTEGRC1.html"  
#  [3] "/inf_corporativa66100_ACESEGC1.html"  
#  [4] "/inf_corporativa71300_ADCOMEC1.html"  
#  [5] "/inf_corporativa10250_HABITAC1.html"  
#  [6] "/inf_corporativa77900_PARAMOC1.html"  
#  [7] "/inf_corporativa77935_PUCALAC1.html"  
#  [8] "/inf_corporativa77600_LAREDOC1.html"  
#  [9] "/inf_corporativa21000_AIBC1.html"     
#  ...
#  ...
```

Comment: Great help, I didn't check the examples in `htmlParse`, but I modified my code with your suggestion. In this case `XML` works great but it takes longer to fetch historical prices from this [web](http://www.bvl.com.pe/jsp/cotizacion.jsp?fec_inicio=20100101&fec_fin=20141130&nemonico=SIDERC1) than `rvest` does.

Comment: Prices? Your question says you're trying to get the links

Comment: Yes, from [this web](http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat) I tried to get all the links from the site, while on [this site](http://www.bvl.com.pe/jsp/cotizacion.jsp?fec_inicio=20100101&fec_fin=20141130&nemonico=SIDERC1) I tried to parse a table that contains historical prices for the SIDERC1 quote. I used `XML` on both sites but I could only use `rvest` on the latter.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Option 1
library(RCurl)
getHTMLLinks('http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat')

# Option 2
library(rvest)
library(pipeR) # %>>% will be faster than %>%
html("http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/empresas_todas.dat")%>>% html_nodes("a") %>>% html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Option 1 seems not to work with the current version of RCurl anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Richard's answer works for HTTP pages but not the HTTPS page I needed (Wikipedia). I substituted RCurl's getURL function as below:

```
library(RCurl)

links <- function(URL) 
{
  getLinks <- function() {
    links <- character()
    list(a = function(node, ...) {
      links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
      node
    },
    links = function() links)
  }
  h1 <- getLinks()
  xData <- getURL(URL)
   htmlTreeParse(xData, handlers = h1)
  h1$links()
}
```